# Liquid Layers - display:none doesnt work

Tags: html, css, layer, liquid

I'm trying to play with "Fluid Layers" and when resizing the window (manually resizing its width), I want to make: display:none on one of the Divs but it fails to do so (simply doesn't work).

Can you tell me why display:none on line 18 doesn't work?. And in addition, Should I use DIVS when i want to center 3 blocks inside a container? or you have a better idea for me?.

Would be happy to get a better / different ideas of implementing Liquid Layers if you know any. thank you for your help.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body
 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }

/* Extra small devices (phones, up to 480px) */
@media (max-width: 480px)
 {
  body
   {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
   }
  .col3 { display: none;  }
 }

/* Extra small devices (usually phones from 480px to 768px) */
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px)
 {
  body
   {
    background-color: yellow;
   }
 }

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
 {
  body
   {
    background-color: #444;
   }
 }

/* Small devices (tablets / desktop, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
 {
  body
   {
    background-color: green;
   }
 }

/* large desktops and up ----------- */
@media (min-width: 1200px)
 {
  body
   {
    background-color: lightblue;
   }
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:100%; margin-left: 0 auto; background-color:#422220; text-align:center; overflow: hidden; padding:10px 0px;">
<div id="col1" style="width:29%; padding: 0; margin-left: 3%; margin-right:3%; background-color:#FFF333; display: inline-  block">Text</div>
<div id="col2" style="width:29%; padding: 0; margin-right:3%; background-color:#FFF333; display: inline-block">Text</div>
<div id="col3" style="width:29%; padding: 0; margin-right:3%; background-color:#FFF333; display: inline-block">Text</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On line 18, you are using 'col3' as class instead of id, try `#col3 { display: none;  }` - https://jsfiddle.net/4uknmLe2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used a class instead of an id as the selector.

Also i moved the common style for all the cols to the stylesheet instead of the inline style as you did.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#col1,
#col2,
#col3 {
  width: 29%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  background-color: #FFF333;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Extra small devices (phones, up to 480px) */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  #col3 {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* Extra small devices (usually phones from 480px to 768px) */

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    background-color: #444;
  }
}
/* Small devices (tablets / desktop, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
/* large desktops and up ----------- */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; margin-left: 0 auto; background-color:#422220; text-align:center; overflow: hidden; padding:10px 0px;">
  <div id="col1">Text</div>
  <div id="col2">Text</div>
  <div id="col3">Text</div>
</div>
```